# Running SharePoint 2010 with Enterprise Mode large file upload issue

Tags: file-upload

Just curious if anyone has experienced an issue with uploading large files when Enterprise mode is used with IE. I'm trying to upload a 200mb file but it fails very time. However if I attempt the same thing with Edge it works fine. Does anyone know if  use of Enterprise mode  interferes with the usual SharePoint max file settings? It appears using Enterprise Mode in IE I am able to upload files up to about 75mb    But using Edge or IE without Enterprise mode I can upload files up to the  500mb size allowed in the settings I have implemented. Anybody have any ideas? Sadly trusty Google has let me down this time.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but don't use EM. Instead, use Compatibility View.

Answer (score 2):

> "By default, the maximum size for uploading files is set to 50 MB. The
>   maximum file size that it can go up to is 2,047 megabytes."

But since you're able to upload files larger than 50 MB with Edge, my guess is that this has already been increased in the web application general setting.

> "While uploading large files, there are chances that the request will
>   timeout. By default, the IIS connection time-out setting is 120
>   seconds."

Track your upload time, and see if you run longer than 120 seconds. If you do, increase the time-out setting in IIS.

Still in trouble? Read more on [Issues Uploading Large Files To SharePoint](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praveenh/2012/11/15/issues-uploading-large-files-to-sharepoint/)

Comment: Thanks Benny....yes all the settings reflect the capacity to upload much larger files. I have successfully uploaded 1gb files without Enterprise Mode. Anyway turns out, after more testing, Enterprise Mode works after all - it just takes much longer: 8 minutes versus 25 seconds for a 250mb file.

Comment: @TutenLab Super. It's not unusual that you have to wait for SharePoint to finish :-)